# Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet.. in Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, dataflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running Dataflow Job from Airflow. I need to say that I am a newie to Airflow. The dataflow (run from Airflow) is running successfully, but I can see that Airflow has some problem with getting job status and I receive infinitely message like:

> Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..

Here are logs just after adding all steps to dataflow (I put {projectID} and {jobID} in places where it was):

```
[2018-10-01 13:00:13,987] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,987] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - b'INFO: Staging pipeline description to gs://my-project/staging'

[2018-10-01 13:00:13,987] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,987] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - b'Oct 01, 2018 1:00:13 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner run'

[2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - b'INFO: To access the Dataflow monitoring console, please navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/jobsDetail/locations/us-central1/jobs/2018-10-01_06_00_12-{jobID}?project={projectID}'

[2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - b'Oct 01, 2018 1:00:13 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner run'

[2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - b"INFO: To cancel the job using the 'gcloud' tool, run:"

[2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,988] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - b'> gcloud dataflow jobs --project={projectID} cancel --region=us-central1 2018-10-01_06_00_12-{jobID}'

[2018-10-01 13:00:13,990] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:13,990] {discovery.py:267} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dataflow/v1b3/rest

[2018-10-01 13:00:14,417] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:14,417] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{projectID}/locations/us-central1/jobs?alt=json

[2018-10-01 13:00:14,593] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:14,593] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:77} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..

[2018-10-01 13:00:29,614] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:29,614] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{projectID}/locations/us-central1/jobs?alt=json

[2018-10-01 13:00:29,772] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:29,772] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:77} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..

[2018-10-01 13:00:44,790] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:44,790] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{projectID}/locations/us-central1/jobs?alt=json

[2018-10-01 13:00:44,937] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2018-10-01 13:00:44,937] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:77} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..
```

Do you know what can cause this? I couldn't find any solution related to this issue.
Should I provide more information?

Here is my task in DAG:

```
# dataflow task
dataflow_t=DataFlowJavaOperator(
task_id='mydataflow',
jar='/lib/dataflow_test.jar',
gcp_conn_id='my_gcp_conn',
delegate_to='{service_account}@{projectID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
dag=dag)
```

and options connected to dataflow in DAG in the default_args:

```
'dataflow_default_options': {
     'project': '{projectID}',
     'stagingLocation': 'gs://my-project/staging'
    }
```

Comment: Are you creating job name in dataflow runner file? It will be easier to debug if you can share dataflow run.py file.

Comment: I specify jobName in DataflowPipelineOptions in java. Like:
[options.setJobName("mydataflow");]
Should I specify it in DAG too? I added how task is specified in issue

Comment: I faced the same issue .i created job name in DataflowPipelineOptions. Airflow also creates job name on the basis of task-id you provide.So there is conflict and airflow is not able to find the actual job name which you created via DataflowPipelineOptions.You should just remove job name from DataflowPipelineOptions and it will work.

Comment: I see indeed that airflow is creating its jobName because in command is:
--jobName=mydataflow-53afd323
but on GCP (after removing job name from DataflowPipelineOptions) i can see it has the name of "dataflowhelper-airflow-1004032710-72d76cab", should i also give some job_name or jobName in DAG?

Comment: just pass task_id in tasks.

Comment: Can you show me what do you mean?

Comment: DataFlowPythonOperator(
    py_file= 'run.py',
    gcp_conn_id=GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
    task_id='cost_preprocess',
    dag=dag,
    options=options,
    retries=0)

Comment: I have task_id specified in DataFlowJavaOperator as you can see above: dataflow_t=DataFlowJavaOperator(
task_id='mydataflow', ...
Is it about this part or something else?

Comment: Yes, same thing.Airflow takes this task-id and creates job.

Comment: Do you know what can cause that dataflow has another name then task_id? as i can see on GCP the name aiflow started is "dataflowhelper-airflow-1004032710-72d76cab"? Not "mydataflow" as specified in task_id

Comment: I see when i run my dataflow locally i get the name "dataflowhelper-magda-1004032710-72d76cab", so with my name in the middle, somehow the job name is still coming from my jar (even it is not specified it creates something default) and not from task_id in DAG

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to get rid of those numbers at the end of jobName generated by Airflow, maybe this could help

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I found the bug, seems that my jar wasn't taking name from command line, I am going to test it

Comment: Yes, that was it, i am able to run my dataflow now :) Thanks once again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I created Job name in DataflowPipelineOptions. 
Airflow also creates job name on the basis of task-id you provide.

```
So there is conflict and airflow is not able to find the actual job name which 
you created via DataflowPipelineOptions.
```

You should just remove job name from DataflowPipelineOptions and it will work.

Comment: I tried but it's still not working, any other suggestion?